# Why can't I change the background of my canvas?

Tags: html, css, canvas

So, I want to make a snake game as a beginner project to get myself into game-making, which is the main reason why I want to code in the first place.

I made my canvas and, after a while, I got it to show up with the border. However, the background of my canvas won't change and I'm not sure why.

I tried using JSHint but it wasn't very helpful.

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="700" height="600" backgroundColor="yellow" style="border:4px solid black;">Good morning</canvas>
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything to the canvas, so... what were you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the background colour in the `style` attribute, like this:

```
 style="border:4px solid black; background-color: yellow"
```

See demo below:

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="700" height="600" style="border:4px solid black; background-color: yellow">Good morning</canvas>
```

Comment: Nevermind. I actually deleted the full rectangle instructions and used fillrect instead. Then I set it equal to a variable. The rectangle doesn't disappear so I'm satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options here: Setting the background color with CSS or using JS to fill the canvas with a colored rectangle.

CSS in HTML style attribute:

`style="border:4px solid black; background: yellow;"`

JS:

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
```